# SharePoint 2010 adding an option to a list item when you right click

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

In SharePoint 2010 I have a list. If you right click on a list item or click on the down arrow you get numerous options.

[image: Right click menu]

I wish to add my own option here. Would anyone know how I can do this. I only want to do it for certain types of documents i.e. docx.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a SharePoint-Feature in which you define a [Custom Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms465980.aspx). Such a feature can be installed on the SharePoint farm. Research Custom Actions using google, you will find lots of tutorials and examples.

In your case you should use the `RegistrationType` of the customaction definition to link the action to a specific content-type. (TopTip: use contenttypes to manage your data, not files types).

Answer (score 0):

I happen to have written a blog series on this subject, which includes some more information on @Dribbel's CustomAction suggestion, as well as a Javascript alternative:

[Editing The SharePoint List Item Menu (Part 1: Using Elements)](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2010/11/editing-the-sharepoint-list-item-menu-part-1-using-elements/)

[Editing The SharePoint List Item Menu (Part 2: Using Javascript)](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2010/11/editing-the-sharepoint-list-item-menu-part-2-using-javascript/)